# Is there any media query for touch devices in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm designing a responsive page that uses a few media queries and I'm trying to make it available on both touch and screens, so I have a rotator that rotates on hover action and I would like to skip it when it comes to touch screens. My question is this: many devices such as netbooks have the same screen size as iPads (iPads in landscape are 1024px which is the same as netbooks). Is there any way that I can write my queries only for touch devices? Something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {.....} /*for netbooks*/

@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {.....} /*for ipads on landscape mode*/
```

Comment: I would look up modernizr

Comment: You can use `media="handheld"` in `link` element, that will include CSS files only for handheld devices (phones, tablets, etc)